# Can I download my own voice greeting in Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I'm trying to download my own voice message (my recorded greeting) from Google Voice. Is there an option to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) service to download your Google Voice data.

This is what the Google Voice archive will contain:

> Your Voice billing history and conversations will be provided as HTML. Greetings and voicemail recordings will be provided as MPEG Audio (mp3). Your list of phones will be provided in the vCard format.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't get _just_ the greetings. I don't have much data in my GV but it was well over a 60MB file. But my greetings were easily found as MP3s.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: You don't need to download it. Recording a new greeting doesn't delete your old one/s.*

If you still want to download your greeting, here's a way to get just the greeting:

1. On Google Chrome, go to [Google Voice - Settings](https://voice.google.com/settings)
2. Play your active greeting
3. Refresh the page
4. Press <kbd>⌥⌘I</kbd> to view Google Chrome's Developer Tools
5. Select the Network tab
6. Play your active greeting
7. Select the name of the request that appears with type media
8. Under Headers > General > Request URL, copy the text after `base64,`

Now, you have your Base64-encoded greeting copied to your clipboard.

- Paste it into a file, eg: `~/Downloads/google-voice/greeting-base64.txt`

On macOS, one way to decode it is by running the following commands in Terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads/google-voice
base64 --decode --input=greeting-base64.txt --output=greeting.mp3
```

I'm not sure if this way gives you the same exact file you get by using Google Takeout, but I think it's the same exact file that plays when you play your greeting from Google Voice - Settings.